# React Native Bridging: Passing JSON to Swift function

Tags: objective-c, json, swift, react-native, objective-c-swift-bridge

Im a rookie in Swift and Objective-C but Im trying to make a bridge from React Native to Swift, and send a JSON and a JSON Array as params to Swift.

Inside React I would like to call this function:

```
startTrack('some url string', { artist: 'Bruce Springsteen', title: 'Born in the USA' }, [{ url: 'url', type: 'image' }, { url: 'another url', type: 'link' ]})
```

So a string, an object, and a object array.

In my bridge objective-c file i have this:

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(startTrack:(NSString *)url trackinfo:(NSDictionary *)trackinfo slides:(NSDictionaryArray *)slides)
```

And in my swift file i have tried a lot of combinations but nothing seems to go through:

```
  @objc func startTrack(url: String, trackinfo: [String: Any], slides: [[String: Any]]) {
    print("Play test", url, trackinfo, slides)
  }
```

I get this error message:
[image: react native error message]

How can I send my params all the way through to my Swift file?

Thanks

/Peter

Comment: I haven't dealt with react too much, but I think it is because you have some syntax issues in your swift code. In your objective c code, you have a parameter: `trackInfo:(NSDictionary *)trackInfo`. In swift 3 this parameter would convert to `,trackInfo trackInfo: [String: Any]` -- This may be your issue.

Comment: If it is, you would probably want to change your methods. Something like: `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(startTrack:(NSString *)url withTrackinfo:(NSDictionary *)trackinfo withSlides:(NSDictionaryArray *)slides)` and `@objc func startTrack(_ url: String,withTrackInfo trackinfo: [String: Any],withSlides slides: [[String: Any]])`

Comment: Still the same error though. I have a feeling that it has to be something with the RCT_EXTERN_METHOD methods way to interpret the json object as a NSDictionary.

Answer (score 8):

Your objective-c method signature set `trackingInfo` as `NSDictionary`, but your Swift method signature accepts a `Dictionary<String: Any>`so this two signature doesn't match.

You have to re-write your method and manually manage NSDictionary to Dictionary cast:

#### Objective-c

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(startTrack:(NSString *)url trackinfo:(NSDictionary *)trackinfo slides:(NSDictionaryArray *)slides)
```

#### Swift

```
@objc func startTrack(url: String, trackinfo: NSDictionary, slides: [NSDictionary]) {
    guard let infoDictionary = trackinfo as? [String: Any],
          let slidesDictionary = slides as? [[String: Any]] else {
        return
    } 
    print("Play test", url, infoDictionary, slidesDictionary)
}
```

#### JS

```
startTrack(
  "some url string",
  { artist: "Bruce Springsteen", title: "Born in the USA" },
  [{ url: "url", type: "image" }, { url: "another url", type: "link" }]
);
```

**notice that you have a typo on JS part

Comment: you are a hero.

Comment: It worked for swift 5.

Comment: Is there any way to make slide conforms to url and type

Answer (score 2):

Your answer did help me alot but still i had one problem

it was fixed by adding `_` in your swift code at start of the line

```
@objc func startTrack(_ url: String, trackinfo: NSDictionary, slides: [NSDictionary]) {
guard let infoDictionary = trackinfo as? [String: Any],
      let slidesDictionary = slides as? [[String: Any]] else {
    return
    } 
print("Play test", url, infoDictionary, slidesDictionary)
}
```