# Pass Optional JSON to Swift from react-native

Tags: objective-c, json, swift, react-native, option-type

Say I have the following Swift class:

```
@objc(ExampleClass)
  class ExampleClass: NSObject {
  init() {}
  @objc func exampleMethod(_ message: String, _ properties: [String: Any]? = nil) -> Void {}
}
```

And the following Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ExampleClass, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(exampleMethod:(NSString *)name (NSDictionary *)properties)
@end
```

Which I then call with the following React Native code:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'

NativeModules.ExampleClass.exampleMethod('example', {'hello': 'world'})
```

This results in the following error message:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:73 Exception 'exampleMethod: is not a recognized Objective-C method.' was thrown while invoking trackEvent on target SegmentTracker with params (
    "example",
        {
        hello = world;
    }
)
```

While calling it like so:

```
NativeModules.ExampleClass.exampleMethod('example')
```

results in:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:73 Exception 'exampleMethod: is not a recognized Objective-C method.' was thrown while invoking trackEvent on target SegmentTracker with params (
    "example"
)
```

I have two questions:
1) How do I pass JSON from React Native to Swift?
2) How do I correctly allow for optional parameters in RCT_EXTERN_METHOD? And if that's not possible, how do I handle the case where I would like to sometimes pass a second parameter, and sometimes not?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with properties of type NSDictionary so that it fits to the interface. It could be similar to:

[react-native-bridging-passing-json-to-swift-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876436/react-native-bridging-passing-json-to-swift-function)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a static method in the swift code
`@objc static func exampleMethod(...`

Answer (score 0):

your swift code should be

```
@objc(ExampleClass)
class ExampleClass: NSObject {
  @objc(exampleMethod:properties:) func exampleMethod(_ message: String, properties: [String: Any]? = nil) -> Void {}
}
```

And your bridge file should be

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ExampleClass, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(exampleMethod:(NSString *)name properties:(NSDictionary *)properties)
@end
```